# Column 'REGION.NAME' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to fetch a list of schools in a region, where the region name from the REGION entity should be equal to the SCHOOLS.REGION_NAME and count the total number of registrations on that particular date, Below is my query in sql server and it is throwing an error related to - is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause., please what could be wrong

```
SELECT 
    p.REGISTRATION_DATE, s.NAME, s.CODE,
    COUNT(number) as total 
FROM
    School p
    INNER JOIN REGION s 
    ON p.REGION_NAME= s.NAME
GROUP BY 
    p.REGISTRATION_DATE
ORDER BY
    total DESC;
```

Here is the result I am trying to expect

```
DATE       | NAME  | CODE  | TOTAL
2020-09-24 | LA    |  LA   |  5
2020-09-25 | CN    |  CN   |  2
```

As you can see from the sample result, on `2020-09-24` region `LA` has total of `5` registrations.

Please what could be wrong?

Comment: Why do you need the `group by` clause? Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the query is missing 2 columns s.NAME, s.CODE from the `GROUP BY` clause.  Also, `ORDER BY` 'total' must reference the underlying column definition and not the label 'total'.  Try

```
SELECT 
    p.REGISTRATION_DATE, s.NAME, s.CODE,
    COUNT(number) as total 
FROM
    School p
    INNER JOIN REGION s 
    ON p.REGION_NAME= s.NAME
WHERE
    p.REGISTRATION_DATE BETWEEN '2020-09-24' AND '2020-09-25'
GROUP BY 
    p.REGISTRATION_DATE, s.NAME, s.CODE
ORDER BY
    total DESC;
```

Comment: Can I fetch in between date ranges using p.REGISTRATION_DATE

Comment: Actually it is totally fine to order by an alias, it's about the only place you can do it. And I tend to recommend that over repeating the expression unless there is a need to differentiate between the alias and an underlying column.